# Handling Server-Side Errors on React: Formik & Yup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, formik, yup

I've been trying to handle error from serverside (i.e. email already exists)

Summary of what I have tried so far:

1. Asynchronously create User Model with email being unique field upon POST /register request.
2. If there's an Error, I will send client side an error using "res.send(e)".
3. await Axios request saving it to variable response under try.
4. On the catch block, set error to field with name 'email'
5. Finally set submitting to false so user can fix the error.

Result: No console.log or error message from the server.

My questions are as follows:

- How do I specify which error I am getting from server-side? (I've tried console logging error blocks by trying to access "e.detail" but I will get undefined.
- How to handle this on client side using Formik and Yup? (What's the best practice?)

Below are my code set up.

My server router setup.

```
const handleErrors = (e) => {
  console.log(Object.values(e));
  res.send(e)
};

module.exports.register_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, name, gender, social, about, interests } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.create({
            email,
            password,
            name,
            gender,
            twitter: social.twitter,
            instagram: social.instagram,
            about,
            interests,
        });
        const token = createToken(user.id);
        console.log(user);
        res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
        res.send(user);
    } catch (e) {
        handleErrors(e);
    }
};
```

My Front-End React(with Formik) side set up

```
const onSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting, setFieldError }) => {
    const filteredValues = _pickBy(values, (_, key) => key !== 'password2');
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/register', {
            ...filteredValues,
        });
        console.log(response);
        history.push('/register/verification');
    } catch (e) {
        setFieldError('email', e);
    } finally {
        setSubmitting(false);
    }
};
```

Comment: You are sending `error` as a response, you won't see an error status until you set it yourself ` res.status(400).send(e)` would tell the browser about error.. ` e.data should provide with the relevant message. However , I think you should send the error like an array ,worked great for for me .`{errors:[{message:'THIS IS ERROR',type:'something'}]}` .It just makes handling so much easier for multiple errors and dont have to handle errors at every component(if you handle it at the top of the react dom and change values based off of the redux values.)

Comment: consistent structure for errors from backend proves beneficial This structure seems good enough since all you really need to check for is , if `errors` key exists on the front end the n you can `.map` over the `errors` array to show the relevant errors as you want.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. It seems like what you just said is the way to go